# how to call LazyRow after API response Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im learning Jetpack Compose and Kotlin, what I need to do is populate a lazyrow with some info from an api, but it seems that Im doing something wrong, since the interface is created and a white screen is shown, in the log I can see that API is called and the response is the object I needed, but the lazyrow never gets recomposed again so the white screen stays like that.

```
This is my code

       @Composable
    fun ParentHomeComposable(
        parentSkills: List<ParentHomeResponseModel>,
    ){
        LazyRow{
            items(
                items = parentSkills,
                key = { parentSkills ->
                    parentSkills.studentId
                }
            ) { parentSkills ->
                ParentItemComposable(
                    ParentItem = parentSkills,
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ParentItemComposable(
        ParentItem: ParentHomeResponseModel,
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints() {
            Box() {
                Column{
                    Box()
                    {
                        Text(
                            text = ParentItem.username,
                            color = DARK_GRAY,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                            maxLines = 2,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


this is my viewmodel

    @HiltViewModel
    class ParentHomeViewModel @Inject
    constructor(
        private val getParentHomeUseCase: GetParentHomeUseCase,
    ) : ViewModel() {
        
        private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ParentHomeUiState())
        val uiState: StateFlow<ParentHomeUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    
        init {
            onGetParentHome()
        }
        
        private fun onGetParentHome() {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                _uiState.update { it.copy(isLoading = true) }
                val parentHomeResponse = getParentHomeUseCase.getParentHome()
                val parentHomeModel = parentHomeResponse.successOr(listOf())
                _uiState.update { parentHomeUiState ->
                    parentHomeUiState.copy(
                        parentHome = parentHomeModel,
                        isLoading = false
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

my parenthomeUiState

    data class ParentHomeUiState(
        val parentHome: List<ParentHomeResponseModel> = listOf(),
        val isLoading: Boolean = false,
        val isDone: Boolean = false
        )


this is the log response

{
    "avatar": "TACO",
    "username": "fdsfss",
    "hodStreak": [false, false, false, false, false],
    "hodPoints": 0,
    "hodRanking": 0,
    "hodTopicsViewed": 15,
    "studentId": "630d786c25430056356c632c",
    "weekProgress": 25,
    "generalProgress": 50,
},
{
    "avatar": "MICHAELL",
    "username": "sffgsf",
    "hodStreak": [false, false, false, false, false],
    "hodPoints": 0,
    "hodRanking": 0,
    "hodTopicsViewed": 15,
    "studentId": "630d901a25430056356c6460",
    "weekProgress": 25,
    "generalProgress": 50,
},

my response model
@Parcelize
data class ParentHomeResponseModel(
    val avatar: String = "",
    val username: String = "",
    val hodStreak: List<Boolean>,
    val hodPoints: Int = 0,
    val hodRanking: Int = 0,
    val hodTopicsViewed: Int = 0,
    val studentId: String = "",
    val weekProgress: Int = 0,
    val generalProgress: Int = 0,
    val exploredTopics:List<ExploredTopics>  ,
): Parcelable{}
```

any ideas? I thought this was really easy but its not working for me

Comment: Please update the code where you are doing api call.

Comment: done, i call the api in the view model, i have debugged this and for some reason it seems to be called twice, in the first time it is called it brings nothing, but the second time it brings the info from the api

Answer (score 1):

I will guess a little based on information on your code

```
ParentHomeComposable(...)
```

takes a list of type `List<ParentHomeResponseModel>`

The problem is that this composable is rendered at first time you compose it (let's say on activity / navigation / fragment start, or when your open this composable with setContent) and without any state that the composable needs to know about it will never change, it will be rendered once.

Now I'm assuming that your are listening to the data inside your activity/fragment like this

```
viewModel.uiState.collect  { yourData ->
   ParentHomeComposable(yourData.parentHome)
}
```

but instead you should be doing

```
  @Composable
    fun ParentHomeComposable(
        parentSkills: List<ParentHomeResponseModel>,
    ){
        val uiState = viewModel.uiState.observeAsState()
        LazyRow{
            items(
                items = uiState.parentHome,
                key = { parentSkills ->
                    parentSkills.studentId
                }
            ) { parentSkills ->
                ParentItemComposable(
                    ParentItem = parentSkills,
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will provide a state to the `LazyRow`.

So, when the `viewmodel` provides a new `uiState`, it will be collected inside the composable and recompose based on the new data.

For more information take a look here

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture

You will get a richer information here

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle